# How to fetch an image from a URL and make it available for download via servlet

Tags: java, servlets, grails

I am trying to fetch an image from a URL and make it available for download from my servlet.

I have the following code and using this I can download the image. However, when I try to open the image, my local OS says: "It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognize."

```
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream")
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=${FilenameUtils.getBaseName(s3Url)}.${FilenameUtils.getExtension(s3Url)}")
InputStream urlStream = new URL(s3Url).openStream()
response.outputStream << IOUtils.toByteArray(new InputStreamReader(urlStream))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you use an `InputStreamReader` which is meant to be used for text content not for binary content, try this `IOUtils.toByteArray(urlStream)`

**NB:** BTW try to avoid `IOUtils.toByteArray` as it loads the content of your image into memory which could lead to `OOME` if you load big images or two many images at the same time.

To avoid loading into memory, you should write the content of the image directly into the `OutputStream` as next:

```
try (InputStream urlStream = new URL(s3Url).openStream();
     OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream()) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = urlStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the alternative to loading the content of the image in memory? Save the image to the file and serve the file and then delete the file?